# Counting duplicate dates in sql

Tags: sql, count

So I have a table with the following data about users and each day they accessed the site:

```
|----DATE----|---User---|  
|2012-01-01  |     Joe  |  
|2012-01-01  |     Jim     |  
|2012-01-01  |     Joe     |  
|2012-01-01  |     Bob     |  
|2012-01-01  |     Joe     |  
|2012-01-02  |     Jane     |  
|2012-01-03  |     Joe     |
```

I want an sql query to count the # of times that a user accessed the site, and show the date only once. It should be organized by date, then the username. Thus, it should look similar to this:

```
|----DATE----|---U---|--Count--|  
|2012-01-03  |     Joe  |  1 |  
|2012-01-02  |     Jane |  1 |  
|2012-01-01  |     Bob  |  1 |  
|2012-01-01  |     Jim  |  1 |    
|2012-01-01  |     Joe  |  3 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to aggregate data, COUNT() will count the occurrences, and we group by user and date to give you what you're after:

```
SELECT DATE, User, COUNT(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY DATE, User
ORDER BY DATE, User
```

You could also order by who accessed the most each day with:

```
SELECT DATE, User, COUNT(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY DATE, User
ORDER BY DATE, COUNT(*)DESC
```

Comment: fantastic, didn't realize it was such a simple answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to determine the total count by using the COUNT aggregate function and then group the returning records by your DATECOLUMN and USERNAME:

```
select DATECOLUMN, USERNAME, count(1) 
    from TABLENAME group by DATECOLUMN, USERNAME
```